# MVC site extenal scripts don't work when deployed as virtual directory

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an MVC application. It's the basic setup where I've made the following change to the About.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/test.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>About</h2>
<p>
     Put content here.
</p>
```

So I've added a reference to an external script.

The script itself contains the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.post('/Home/GetResult', null, function (data) {

        alert(data);

    });

});
```

The method called in the home controller is:

```
public int GetResult()
        {
            return 3;
        }
```

So, it's a basic setup where the user clicks on the about the GetResult method is called and an alert pops up containing 3.

So I set this up in IIS as a Website and it works as expected. When About is clicked the message pops up and the website
has the address `http://localhost:xx/Home/About`

I then tried setting it up as a virtual directory.

When About is clicked on no message pops up.
The url for where it goes is: `http://localhost:xx/Practise/Home/About` where practise is the name of the virtual directory.

So why is the message not coming up?

Can it no longer find the file now that the url contains the virtual directory name?

What would be the best way of fixing this if it were required to be hosted as a virtual directory?

Comment: check the HTML source to see where the .js file is being loaded from, see if you can open it in your browswer.  Try changing its URL to /Practise/Scripts/test.js

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the hardcoded url.  Try it like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.post('@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")', null, function (data) {

        alert(data);

    });

});
```

Always using the Url helper functions takes care of the actual physical names for you

Comment: well it's in an external javascript file so I can't use that helper. Does this mean you can't use external javascript files with posts like that if it's a virtual directory?

Comment: How is =@Url.Content("~/Scripts/test.js") an external script?  Anyway, you can have external scripts hit your pages, but in that case you have to do it hardcoded so you have all the problems when something moves.  Your best bet is probably something like IIS URL Rewrite http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite - note, I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically what I do in situations like this is to have the URL written in the page via routing, and have the library consume a well known variable or take an object at initialization:

In your page:

```
var getResultUrl = '@Url.Action(...)';
```

In your script file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post(getResultUrl, null, function (data) {

        alert(data);
    });
});
```

You have to be careful of order of operations on stuff like this, where the page script needs to run before the include script, or you need to do something else to invoke it (wrap it in a function).